# Google Chrome Cookie Storage

Tags: macos, cookies, google-chrome, storage

Where does the latest Google Chrome for Mac save cookies, specifically those that expire with the session?

Comment: Why would session cookies be kept anywhere other than the browser's main memory? It's supposed to not stick around after you quit the browser.

Comment: Well, what I meant is, how can I see it in the Finder?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The cookies are in a sqlite3 database named `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies`. The session cookies are not stored on the disk.

Comment: Thanks! Still, is there any way to modify the session cookies?

Comment: Probably with the JavaScript console in the developer tools.

Comment: There is a chrome extension Edit This Cookie, may be that may help. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg

Comment: This only gives me the .sol files. How can I see the cookie information?

Comment: "is there any way to modify the session cookies?" its in a sqlite database so obviously you can edit it directly from the shell or with a GUI sqlite editor.

Answer (score 1):

The file is a SQL database you can see and change the contents with SQLite Database Browser witch can be easily found for download in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this was posted 6 years ago, maybe this could still be helpful: did you mean to ask where can you find the cookies and localstorage and resources on chrome's devTools **on mac os?** 
It's under "application" tab.

Comment: No. The OP said: "what I meant is, how can I see it in the Finder?"

Answer (score 0):

Josh Lee's answer is correct, however, if you're having trouble finding the cookies in Finder, it's probably because they're located within the hidden 'Library' folder in your user's home directory.

The easiest way to get there is just open Finder, open the 'Go' menu up top, and press 'Go to Folder'. Then just paste in the path and hit go;

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies
```

If you want to be able to view hidden files and folders in OS X you should run the following command in the Terminal;

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Once you've done that, hold the Alt key (option key) and right-click on the finder icon in your Dock, and click Relaunch. Now when you open a finder window you can see hidden files and folders.