# Check existing cookies for chrome browser on Mountain Lion

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, osx-mountain-lion

I would like to check what are the values for existing cookies on my Mac Mountain Lion OSX 10.8.2 ? I believe there is a cookies folder on Windows. Where should I look for something similar on Mac?

Comment: Cookie storage is browser specific, not operating system specific. This doesn't seem to be a programming question anyway.

Comment: Have you tried Googling?  I see you tagged this under Google Chrome.  You could try searching for "view cookies chrome".

Comment: This may help for folks who search for Mountain Lion and @Quentin Cookie storage does differ from one Operating System to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohk, I had searched for mountain lion so could not find it but when just searched for chrome, found this 
[Google Chrome Cookie Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528208/google-chrome-cookie-storage)

which answers it for mac.